# Display Facebook Event Page On Website with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to display the events from a clients Facebook page on their website. I've spent hours searching for this, and I've found several solutions, but they seem to all point to an older version of Facebook's API.

I was able to find some info on Facebook's site itself, but unfortunately I'm not a very skilled PHP programmer, nor am I familiar with Facebook's API and so I can't seem to figure it out. Here's Facebooks page explaining their API concerning Events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event

Also, here's a reference to a stackoverflow post that addresses my issue, but appears to be for an older version of Facebook's API: [Display a public Facebook event on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971990/display-a-public-facebook-event-on-a-web-page)

oliakaoil suggested that I give an example, so here's one of the things I tried, which didn't work.

```
<?php 
require '/home/diamonds/public_html/facebook/';
$fb = new Facebook(array(
       'appid'=>'Your-AppID',
       'secret'=>'Your-AppSecret'
      ) );
$page_events = $fb->api('/ikeausa/events', 'GET');
printf ('<pre>%s</pre>', $page_events);
 ?>
```

My problem comes with referencing the Facebook SDK, and if I ever got past that, the other code might not work either. I've uploaded the newest Facebook SDK, but I can't figure out how to reference it properly. It appears that the old SDK might have been a simple single page "Facebook.php", but on the newer SDK, it's a folder full of a bunch of php files. If it was one file, I think I could figure out how to reference it, but I don't know enough to figure out how to reference the whole folder full of files. Also, even if I did know how to reference it, I'm not sure I'd know how to use the properties right.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty much a beginner in this area, so what I could really use is an example of how to do it. It seems like something that a lot of people would have wanted to do, and so it would seem that there would be an example out there somewhere. Whenever, I go to look for examples, though, they all seem to be code for the old SDK. It's a recurring problem I've had with a lot of code I've looked for. Google seems to preference old out-of-date results and it makes it hard to find relevant up-to-date answers.

Comment: Your question is too broad, unfortunately for this forum. Try writing some code, or at least some psuedo-code, start getting some feedback from your work, then post your results here and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Just in case you guys want a complete and step by step tutorial, this page is exactly what you want https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/07/display-facebook-events-to-your-website.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That was the kind of thing I had been looking for. Since I already got something to work, I think I'll stick with it for now, but I'll try to keep that in mind for later. It looks like I would have more control over what happened with the method described in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two months later, I came back to this problem with fresh eyes and tried a different search on Google. I immediately found an acceptable solution to the problem. I should specify that the answer I found displays a feed of your posts, not events like I originally requested, but for my purposes it works.

The solution was to use Facebook's Like Box feature. You can find instructions for using that feature here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ In order to show a stream of current posts, you'll want to make sure to use the option `data-stream="true"`.

I'll copy some sample code here for convenience:
Right after the `<body>` tag of your page, place this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=683879905040205&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then, wherever you want the box to go, past this code:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-height="500" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

You'll want to replace "FacebookDevelopers" in the url with whatever your page url is.

In addition to toggling the basic options that Facebook gives for the Like Box, I wanted to make the box dynamically size up or down based on the page size. I was able to get it to do this by following the directions provided here: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/create-responsive-facebook-like-box-wordpress/

The sizing code, which you stick in your css is as follows:

```
.fb_iframe_widget {display: block !important;} 
.fb-like-box iframe {width: 100% !important;} 
.fb-like-box span {width: auto !important; position: initial !important;}
.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span {width:100% !important;}
.fb_iframe_widget span {position: static !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this was for WordPress? [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-events-importer/) is free and includes all the functions you need to return the values from latest Facebook SDK. MakExample of the code below.

```
            <?php 
                    $args = array (
                        'post_type' => 'facebook_events',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                    );

                    $fbe_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if( $fbe_query->have_posts() ): 
                    while ( $fbe_query->have_posts() ) : $fbe_query->the_post();

                      $event_title = get_the_title();
                      $event_desc =  get_the_content();
                      $event_image = get_fbe_image('cover');

                ?>
                  <img src="<?php echo get_fbe_image('cover'); ?>" alt="" />
                  <h1><?php echo $event_title; ?></h1>
                  <p><?php echo $event_desc; ?></p>    
                <?php

                     endwhile;
                     endif;

                wp_reset_query();  

                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood.

Try this:

you need 4 things to do:
facebook API PHP,
AppID, AppSecret And an Authtoken.

You can get at developers.facebook

and try this code:

```
    <?php
    require './facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'put_your_app_id_here',
        'secret' => 'put_your_app_secret_here',
        'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
    ));

    try{
        $events=$facebook->api('/fanpage_here/events?access_token=access_token_here');
    }catch (FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
    }

    foreach ($events["data"] as $event){

        $startTime=strtotime($event["start_time"]);



     if ((time()-$startTime)<=60*60*24*1 || $startTime>time()){
                try{

                $ev=$facebook->api('/'.$event["id"]);
                    }catch (FacebookApiException $e){

                    error_log($e);
                        }


      ?>
                        <div>
                            <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $event["id"]; ?>/picture?type=small" align="left" />
                            <b>Name:</b> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=<?php echo $event['id']; ?>"><?php echo $event['name'];    ?></a><br>
                            <b>Time:</b> <?php echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A",strtotime($event["start_time"])); ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo date("l jS 
                            \of F Y h:i:s A",strtotime($event["end_time"])); ?><br>
                            <b>Location:</b> <?php echo $ev["location"]; ?><br>
                            <b>Description:</b> <?php echo substr( $ev["description"] ,0,250);?><?php print("...");?><br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                }


    }
?>
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I tried the above code, but it gave me this error: "Failed opening required './facebook.php'". Where would I get facebook.php. I'm not sure facebook.php is included in the most recent SDK. I wouldn't mind using the old SDK if I found it, but it sounds like that code will stop being supported in April of 2015.

Comment: Thanks for showing me where to find it. I believe that is the older SDK, though. I think support for it will run out in a year. Also, I'm not sure I'm permitted to use the older SDK since I just got my Facebook developer app id today. ... I did decide to try to use it, though, and I got further than I have before. It didn't error out, but instead of giving my events page, it loaded the page that you gave me the link to.